# Gradle cannot find classes from another module when running tests

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, junit, module

I have created a very basic test app where I have two modules:

- The default app module (app)
- A dynamic feature module (dynamic feature)

In the dynamic feature module I have written a test that imports a simple data class (Tester.kt) from the app module.

In the app module:

```
package com.example.testapp

data class Tester(val isWorking: Boolean)
```

In the dynamic feature module:

```
package com.example.dynamicfeature

import com.example.testapp.Tester
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert.*

class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun `can load class from app module`() {
        val test = Tester(true)
        assertEquals(true, test.isWorking)
    }
}
```

The project compiles fine, Android studio has no errors with importing the module or finding the dependencies, and the test runs fine when I run it in Android Studio.

However, when I try to run the tests with gradle:

`./gradlew test`

I get the error:

```
com.example.dynamicfeature.ExampleUnitTest > can load class from app module FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at ExampleUnitTest.kt:16
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at ExampleUnitTest.kt:16

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

The settings.gradle is:

```
include ':dynamicfeature'
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "TestApp"
```

To reproduce checkout the repository at:
https://github.com/dlmcauslan/TestApp.git

Does anyone have any idea why gradle cannot find a class in the app module?

Comment: Can you share your settings.gradle?

Comment: I've updated the question to include settings.gradle. As well as a link to a repository which reproduces the issue.